# Can I make this PL SQL trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have Three tables BORROW , PAID and COMPLETED

BORROW Table Have 3 fields
UID(Primary Key)
AMOUNT

PAID Table have 
UID(Forign Key)
INSTALLMENT

COMPLETED Table have 
UID(Forign Key)
AMOUNT

```
If i borrow $100 from some one 

BORROW TABLE will be

| UID | AMOUNT |
| 1   | 100    |
----------------

PAID TABLE 


| UID | INSTALLMENT |
|-----|------------|
| 1   | 30         |
--------------------
| 1   | 40         |
--------------------
| 1   | 10         |
--------------------
| 1   | 20         |
--------------------
```

I need to automatically transfer details of  BORROW TABLE into  A COMPLETED TABLE
WHEN SUM(INSTALLMENT) = AMOUNT WHERE UID =1;

Somebody please help me to make a trigger for the above operation

Answer (score -1):

You can create a stored procedure / query to call after each INSERT/UPDATE on PAID. It would contain something like :

```
-- @UID is your UID from PAID when inserted/updated
DECLARE @SUM int
DECLARE @BILL int

SELECT @SUM = SUM(INSTALLMENT)
FROM PAID
WHERE UID = @UID
GROUP BY UID

SELECT @BILL = AMOUNT
FROM BORROW
WHERE UID = @UID

IF @BILL = @SUM
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO COMPLETED (UID, AMOUNT)
    VALUES (@UID, @BILL)
END
```

You will need to change this query depending on what you need but the basic idea is here.

EDIT : Didn't know that you can't access your own table on a trigger event for Oracle. It looks like it's impossible to go for a trigger in this special case.

Comment: The OP asked for Oracle PL/SQL. In Oracle a row-level trigger cannot query its own table, and attempts to work around the problem tend to hit read consistency issues in a multi-user system.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Then you can go for solution n°2